# Implementing configuration for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms application that supports iOS, Android, and UWP. I am looking for a way to implement config file (which Xamarin.Forms doesn't have out of the box). I found this:

https://xamarinhelp.com/configuration-files-xamarin-forms/

But it uses PCL, which is obsolete, as I heard. Is there a more modern working implementation?

Comment: https://github.com/AgustinBonilla/ConfigPlugin

Comment: @Jason Thank you for the suggestion. I am facing the same issue as with the solution I mentioned in my question: Configuration class and json files must be in the folder {PCL_Project}\Config. Maybe it is not a problem, I just don't know. What is PCL_Project anyway? Also, does it support UWP?

Comment: They are referring to the shared project.  PCL is an old project type, nowadays .NET Standard is used instead

Comment: @Jason Oh, so it is just a shared project. So does it support UWP?

Comment: Yes, XF supports UWP

Comment: @Jason Actually, I meant whether the solution you suggested supported UWP. I assume it does. I will try it tomorrow. Thank you very much again.

Comment: @Jason This seems to be a good solution. Could you please make it an Answer, and I will mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an existing plugin that does this

https://github.com/AgustinBonilla/ConfigPlugin